# Notificaciones JavaScript no funcionan en el hosting pero si en localhost

Tags: javascript, hosting, notificaciones

hay respuestas de esto aquí en la comunidad stack-overflow pero ninguna me da con la solución, además me parece muy raro que funcionen normal como si nada en mi localhost. así que llegue a pensar que son problemas de configuración del host o ¿Qué puede ser?, el resto de mi JavaScript funciona bien. agradecería mucho la ayuda

```
function showNotificationDesigner() {
    if (!Notification) {
        $('body').append('<h4 style="color:red">*Browser no soporta notificaciones web</h4>');
        return;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
            url : "./backend/notification.php?accion=consultar",
            success: function(resp) {
        var json = JSON.parse(resp);
                if(json['success']) {
          if (json['notificaciones']) {
            page=$('#page').attr('data-nombre')
            console.log(page)
            if (page=="listaSolicitudes"|| page=="enviarSolicitud") {

                    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (resp){
                  console.log(resp)
                  if (resp==="granted") {
                    generarNotificaciones(json['notificaciones'], json['rol'])
                  }else {
                    console.log('sin permiso')
                  }
                })
            }

            if (json['notificaciones'].length!=0) {
              html=htmlNotificacionesNavbar(json['notificaciones'], json['rol'])
              $('#sp_notificaciones').html(html)
              eventEliminarNotificaciones(json['notificaciones'])
              html=`
              <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
              <span class="num font-weight-bold">${json['notificaciones'].length}</span>
              `
              $('a.icon-bell.mx-0').html(html)
            }

          }
                }
        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
            }
        });
    }//fin if
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da? ¿Si accedes directamente a `./backend/notification.php?accion=consultar` te funciona correctamente?

Comment: El problema es que no me da ningún error, es como si ignorara el pedir el permiso de la notificación. Insisto, en local lo hace normal, pide el permiso si no se le a concedido y lanza la notificación y en el host montado no. He llegado a pensar que es alguna configuración del host.

Comment: A y si va hasta notificaciones.php ya que las puedo listar en la consola y todo en la respuesta del Ajax. El problema es lanzar la notificación, ni un "hola" me lanza :'c

Comment: Más o menos entiendo lo que quieres decir. Mi pregunta es: si ejecutas de manera aislada el POST de tu código desde la consola, ¿funciona?.  Si llamas manualmente desde consola a `showNotificationDesigner()` ¿hace algo? Si añades puntos de interrupción en el debugger ¿Llega a algún punto?